# Zend Framework 2 - Sending form using Zend\Mail

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, sendmail

So i'm making a contact page. Of course it will have a form, which needs to be sent.
I made the class to send email:

```
<?php
namespace Site\Mail;

use Zend\Mail\Message;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail;

class SendEMail {

    public function SendEMail($to, $from, $subject, $body) {
        $message = new Message();
        $message->addTo($to)
                ->addFrom($from)
                ->setSubject($subject)
                ->setBody($body);
        $transport = new Sendmail();
        try {
            $transport->send($message);
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

In the controller i have

```
public function emailAction () {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $vm = new ViewModel();
    $vm->setTerminal(true);
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $to = "some@mail.com";
        $from = $request->getPost("email");
        $subject = "Messaggio inviato da ".$request->getPost("nome")." (tel. ".$request->getPost("phone").")";
        $body = $request->getPost("messaggio");
        $mail = new SendEMail($to, $from, $subject, $body);

        if (!$mail) {
            $vm->setVariables(array(
                "result" => "no"
            ));
            return $vm;
        } else {
        $vm->setVariables(array(
            "result" => "yes"
        ));
        return $vm;
        }
    }
    $vm->setVariables(array(
            "result" => "This script needs POSTDATA."
    ));
    return $vm;
}
```

I disabled the layout to allow an Ajax/Jquery script to load it, and it works like a charm (i'll show you it although i don't think it's causing my issue)

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:$("form").attr("action"),
        method:"POST",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("form").css("opacity", 0.5);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $("form").css("opacity", 1);
        },
        success: function(responseText) {
            $("body").append("<div id='popupmessage'>"+responseText+"</div>");
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            $("body").append("<div id='popupmessage'>"+errorThrown+"</div>");
        }
    }).always(function() {
        $("#popupmessage").delay(1000).fadeOut(300, function () {
            if($(this).length>0) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

The problem is that my `SendEMail()` function looks like always return true, even if i put wrong settings in sendmail.ini (and i'm using sendmail).
What's my mistake? I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was implementing my email method I was never able to get the exception with:

> catch (\Exception $e) {
>               return false;}

For me it was not so important to get it though. But at some point I noticed that I was getting an exception when the domain did not exist or it was wrong so I narrowed down the exception to.

```
} catch (\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException $e) {
            $error = true;
        }
```

So if this is not what you want I would assume that making this change would provide you more than the runtimeException or you can keep it the way it is assuming this return you the result you want

```
} catch (\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception $e) {
                $error = true;
            }
```

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Update:

I noticed I am using SMTP Transport ([more details](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mail.transport.html)) So that is why I am using the protocol Exception. If you check inside the Zend Library you will see another folder Zend\Mail\Exception. So try that inside the try catch e.g.

```
} catch (\Zend\Mail\Exception $e) {
    $error = true;
 }
```

If this does not work try to narrow down the exception: Inside the folder you will see 6 exception classes test each one inside the try catch (\Zend\Mail\Exception\AnExceptionClass)

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's still returning true all the time. I'm beginning to think that it's supposed to act this way: maybe have sendmail with bad settings is not enough to throw an exception...

Comment: ok i noticed something so please read the update, maybe this time we get it right

Comment: Well I cant think of anything else. Maybe you can use the SMTP Transport   method if its important that you get the exception and test if that will return the exception.

Comment: Wait Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail has an exception folder inside so why not try that (Zend\Mail\Transport\Exception) since you are using that method

Comment: <code>Zend\Mail\Transport\Exception</code> returns true. Well i wanted to throw exceptions just to let the user know if mail wan't sent. But well after all there are many things that can make it fail even after execution...maybe i'm trying to do an impossible thing